# Generic routing rule => Content type gets wrong value

Tags: content-type, content-organizer

We've about 100 content types. For 10 of those content types I've created a specific routing rule. The other 90 content types are catched by a routing rule with as content type our base content type "Customer Document" with an asterisk as alias. This is working, documents are routed, but there is one issue. All documents are reset to the base content type "Customer Document", no matter what the original content type was.
If I create a specific routing rule for one of those 90 content types and upload as that content type, it works.

I've tried to debug the SharePoint code responsible for routing a document, but that is a big, big mess. Anyone an idea?

Comment: Do those 90 content types have required fields? Also, would you be opposed to using a workflow instead of a routing system?

Comment: Yeah they have required fields.
And, why use workflows? It is working if I add a separate rule for each content type.... But that's not really flexible of course.

Comment: I understand. If a product deems useful, it should be tested thoroughly and used every which way. However, it may be a bug. Have you looked into event receivers? That would be my next option.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for other workarounds. I have a workaround (use one routing rule / event receiver).
If anyone comes across this post: Call Microsoft support, it's a bug in SP.